# Missing Swagger documentation with Springdoc for @RepositoryRestResource

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springdoc, spring-repositories

I've created annotated repository, but no Swagger definition is visible

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "InstanceUptime")
public interface InstanceUptimeRepository extends  JpaRepository<InstanceUptime, Long> {
  @Override
  @RestResource(exported = false)
  void delete(InstanceUptime entity);
}

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>    
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>    
  <version>1.6.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Do I need to do something more to make it working?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Spring docs](https://springdoc.org/#spring-data-rest-support):

> The projects that use `spring-data-rest` can add the following
> dependency (`springdoc-openapi-data-rest`) **in combination with the `springdoc-openapi-ui`
> dependency**.

So both dependencies should be added to the `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>    
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>    
  <version>1.6.14</version>
</dependency>
```